# MS Access: Calculate First Day of Next Quarter based on Date field

Tags: ms-access

On a MS Access Table, I would like to have a column that has the first day of the following quarter based on a date in another column.

For example, I have a `Start_Date` column with a value of `2018-02-04`, I would like the record on that column to show that the following quarter would start on `2018-04-01`.

I have this working fine in Excel using the following formula:

> =DATE(YEAR(M2),((INT((MONTH(M2)-1)/3)+1)*3)+1,1)

In Access, I added the column choosing `Calculated Field` > `Date/Time`, but could not figure out a way to get it to work like an Excel.

Has anyone tried this before or know of a possible solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
Public Function DateNextQuarterFirst( _
  Optional ByVal datDateThisQuarter As Date) As Date

  Const cintQuarterMonthCount   As Integer = 3

  Dim intThisMonth              As Integer

  If datDateThisQuarter = 0 Then
    datDateThisQuarter = Date
  End If
  intThisMonth = DatePart("q", datDateThisQuarter) * cintQuarterMonthCount

  DateNextQuarterFirst = DateSerial(Year(datDateThisQuarter), intThisMonth + 1, 1)

End Function
```

To use it in a query with SQL similar to this:

```
Select *, DateNextQuarterFirst([Start_Date]) As NextQuarterFirst
From YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. Is this a Macro? VBA? While having worked with Access before, I haven't done any programming, so any place to start would be helpful.

Comment: Yes. Create a new module. Copy and paste the function into it. Go to menu Debug, Compile - then save the module.

Comment: Thanks. I got it in the module. Only, I don't need it in a query, I need it to populate in the column I prepared for it.

Comment: You shouldn't. It's bad behaviour to store calculated values. A no-no. If you insist, create an update query using the function to update the field value.